# Django i18n pattern

Tags: python, django, internationalization, django-i18n

I'm using internationalization.

So, everyhting works fine, when I access `http://localhost:8000/en/` and `http://localhost:8000/de/`

But when I access `http://localhost:8000/` it redirects me to `http://localhost:8000/en/` even when the last accessed page was `http://localhost:8000/de/`

Basically, I want to save language code, based on the page accessed, e.g. if I access `http://localhost:8000/de/` then language is german. Next, when I access `http://localhost:8000`, it should point me to `http://localhost:8000/de/`, not default `http://localhost:8000/en/`

How this can be done?

Comment: Have you configured cookies?

Comment: No. I don't know how and where to do it.

Comment: It's been a while since I used Django but here's the section on how Django discovers the language: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that Django didn't add request.session['django_language'] = lang_code

I just extend locale middleware and use the following code.

```
def process_request(self, request):

    if self.is_language_prefix_patterns_used():
        lang_code = (get_language_from_path(request.path_info) or
                     request.session.get('django_language', settings.LANGUAGE_CODE))

        activate(lang_code)
        request.session['django_language'] = lang_code
        request.LANGUAGE_CODE = get_language()
```

Now, I have following question.
What should I do so that
http://localhost:8000 didn't redirect (to prefix with language code)?

I found following code:

```
class NoPrefixLocaleRegexURLResolver(LocaleRegexURLResolver):

@property
def regex(self):
    language_code = get_language()
    if language_code not in self._regex_dict:
        regex_compiled = (re.compile('' % language_code, re.UNICODE)
                          if language_code == settings.LANGUAGE_CODE
                          else re.compile('^%s/' % language_code, re.UNICODE))

        self._regex_dict[language_code] = regex_compiled
    return self._regex_dict[language_code]
```

However, there is problem with that code in checking if `language_code == settings.LANGUAGE_CODE`. If I enter `http://localchost:8000`, it will not redirect, but supply a page with translation from `settings.LANGUAGE_CODE` instead of `request.session.get('django_language')`. As I understood, I can't access request, so what should be done?

Answer (score 0):

In order for the described behavior to work, the current language has to be persisted in either the `session` or a `cookie`. When using Django's `set_language` redirect view for switching languages, it takes care for that:

**Language switcher with [`set_language`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/translation/#the-set-language-redirect-view) redirect-view**

This view receives the new language through a `POST` request and afterwards updates the session (or cookie) so that the language preference gets persisted.

Example language switcher from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/translation/#the-set-language-redirect-view):

Requires `django.core.context_processors.i18n` in `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PREPROCESSORS` and the i18n views to be in the project's `urls.py`.

```
<form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ redirect_to }}" />
    <select name="language">
        {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
        {% for language in languages %}
            <option value="{{ language.code }}"{% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>
                 {{ language.name_local }} ({{ language.code }})
            </option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

**Explicitly persisting the language of a requested page on each request**

Another option would be to [set it explicitly](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/translation/#explicitly-setting-the-active-language), although this would have to be done from within each request (probably in a custom middleware) so that it is guaranteed to pick up each address change that might occur when the user manually changes the language prefix in the browser's address bar. (While comparing a plain *Django* and a *Django CMS* setup I've noticed that Django CMS supports the behavior out of the box, so it might be an idea to look at their repo to see how they have done that.)

Answer (score 0):

What you are experiencing is that your language selection is not sticking as it should and so to do this there are a few things to check.

My guess is that you have 'en' as your LANGUAGE_CODE in your settings so that will always be your fallback. Quite often the reason that you cannot get your language to stick is that you may not have the correct middleware in your settings MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES.

Try the following checklist to see if you have everything you need:

- Add SessionMiddleware and LocaleMiddleware to your middleware stack in your settings, ensure the SessionMiddleware comes before LocaleMiddleware as it relies on the use of sessions and it is responsible for fetching your desired language from a request via the url/session/cookie/request header in that order I believe, then uses your fallback language if all else fails.
- Ensure all languages that you want to serve are in your LANGUAGES list in settings

That should hopefully do the trick so hope that helps.